# Android Studio - Why is there an invisible icon in tray?

Tags: windows, android-studio, system-tray

When I run Android Studio, a new icon appears in the system tray of Windows.
The icon is fully transparent, and doesn't react to clicks (both right and left clicks).

Why is it there and how do I fix it if it's not supposed to be there?

[image: Screenshot depicting the problem]

Comment: You can disable it by deselecting Android Studio in the tray bar icon settings, but I don't know why it's there.

Comment: I know that, but I just don't know if it's a good idea. I always prefer to manage tray icons from the apps themselves.

Comment: Me too! They should give it an icon and a description atleast. Looks like some spyware at the beggining.

Comment: It looks like they are trying their best to make Windows look bad :))

Comment: Is there any way to remove this icon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it's there to let Android Studio notify about finished builds and such.
There was [a bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-207320) where it had no icon, but now it has ([image: The tray icon]).